# mysql not starting up on wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am trying to start up mysql via WAMP ("Start all services"), but the WAMP icon in the task bar remains orange, and mysql remains unstarted. I examined the error log and this is what I found:

```
131220 17:13:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131220 17:13:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131220 17:13:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
131220 17:13:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131220 17:13:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131220 17:13:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
131220 17:13:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131220 17:13:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131220 17:13:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131220 17:13:01 [ERROR] Aborting

131220 17:13:01 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? After seeing the error log I thought innodb was not on so I set innodb = on in my.ini, but that didn't work either.

If it helps: WAMP worked fine before, but yesterday I shutdown mysql manually like

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

and now WAMP doesn't work. Perhaps that has something to do with the problem I'm encountering?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/104014/innodb-error-log-file-ib-logfile0-is-of-different-size

Comment: This is a miracle! Deleting both ib_log0 and ib_log1 worked! Though I don't get why.

Comment: I also dont recall making any changes to the log_file_size ...